# iTunes does not load new tracks from the library

Tags: windows, itunes, music-management

I have a big music library, I configured iTunes in settings the following path: `C:\Users\-\Music`.

The first time I did this it loaded all my MP3 files from folders and subfolders.

Then I downloaded new music into an specific folder called 2012, but the library is not updated, it still shows me the old files but not the new ones.

I closed and opened iTunes again, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes does not automatically update its library. I don't know why, but it has always been this way. You have to go to File -> Add Folder to Library and select the same folder you already added to have it search again. It will add anything that has changed since the last time you added the folder.

Comment: doesnt it add duplicated tracks?

Comment: Nope. If its in the library already it skips it and only adds what has changed. My library is modest, roughly 3000 songs, and ive been adding to it for months on this computer, ive probably done File -> add folder to library two dozen times. If it duplicated them id have so many more. It won't hurt it any.